# Solve system $ 3\cos(3x)=\sin(x+2u), 3\sin(2x+u)=-\cos(3u)$.

Tags: trigonometry

Solve system $ 3\cos(3x)=\sin(x+2u),  3\sin(2x+u)=-\cos(3u)$.

I tried to transform    $\cos(3x)=4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)$ , but in vain...

Answer (score 2):

Try the following: $$3\cos 3x=\sin(x+2u) \\ -\cos 3u =\sin(2x+u) $$ Multiply both the equations: $$-\frac{3}{2} \cdot 2\cos 3x \ \cos3u = \frac{3}{2} \cdot 2\sin(x+2u)\sin(2x+u) \\ -\cos(3(x+u))-\cos(3(x-u)) = \cos(x-u) -\cos(3(x+u)) \\ \cos t+ \cos 3t =0 $$ where $t= x-u$. Can you solve for $t$ and substitute one of the variables back in one if the equations to end ?

Comment: You have to take extra care of not multiplying an equation by zero.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Yes, but one can plug in the final values obtained in the initial equation to eliminate any extraneous solutions.